# Use of valedictions in non-personal communication

Tags: writing-style, valediction

Would it be proper to use a [valediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction) ("complimentary close") in a newspaper or magazine message wholly devoted to congratulating the media's readers with the New Year or some other holiday?

An example message from the staff of a made-up media:

> Dear readers!
>
> From the bottom of our hearts we...
>
> Yours sincerely, Russian Industrial News' editorial staff.

Or are valedictions more fit for personal communication?

P.S. In Russia, such congratulatory newspaper messages are ended with a no-frills bottom-positioned line like "Editorial staff of [name of media]." I became curious whether this would work in an English-language media, or should one add something to embellish the ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you cannot use such an expression. Especially, if it's complimentary, and is aimed at connecting with the readers, there can't be a reason stopping you from using it.

No additional wording is necessary; I suspect in general, English is on the whole a more informal language than Russian.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some form of salutation, I would say you need some form of valediction. If the tone of the message is particularly emotive for a newspaper, then ending it with an equally sentimental valediction would be justified. Typically though, I think ending with a simple "-Editorial staff" would suffice.